# Does the phrase "voice an opinion" have some negative connotations?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, connotations

Does the phrase *voice an opinion* have some negative connotations?

For example let us take this sentence:

> User123456 in several comments on meta recently voiced the opinion that creation of a tag should always be discussed on meta first.

Does the use of the phrase *voice an opinion* somehow indicate that this user was a bit too aggressive in getting his point through? Would choosing some other word instead be more polite?

The reason I am asking is that *voice* might be associated with *loud voice*, so it could be a metaphor for being loud.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the tags which exists here at ELL. If some more experienced user sees my posts and has some ideas for better choice of tags, please, do edit my question.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it does have a slight negative connotation.  But it's not that **voice** suggests loudness.

Whenever anyone makes a point of distinguishing between saying something and thinking it, one or the other is being criticized, if only by implication.  q.v. "You're just saying that."

The phrase "to voice the opinion" is a deliciously subtle example, because it contains within it the distinction that someone both had an opinion and expressed it.  It is otherwise a synonym for "said" or "expressed" or "opined" or "suggested" or "proposed":

> User123456 in several comments on meta recently **proposed** that creation of a tag should always be discussed on meta first.

So the choice to use the idiom "voiced the opinion" is significant.  It has a chilliness to it.  It doesn't make plain exactly what the complaint is, but has a slight asperity to it, as if it were a mild version of "felt the need to tell us".

Comment: I like the phrase 'slight asperity' - that describes it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it **always** shows negation. Take this example from the [WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/VOICE) -

> *He voiced his concern*

On [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/voice_2), it says - ***to tell*** people your feelings or opinions about something. I don't see any negation there. Probably you are confused with the typical use of *voice* word in *I raised my voice...* there it could be a strong word stating some aggression (but still not negation).